# One trigger for two control templates

Tags: wpf

I have **button** and custom **template** for it. In the template I have **two buttons inside a grid**. **Each** button has own **custom template**. Also I have a **trigger** IsMouseOver for this **root grid**. My goal is change **style for both buttons** when mouse is over. But TargetName attribute of Setter does not have access to nested controltemplate's controls.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource DropDownStyle}" Content="Downloads"/>

<Style x:Key="DropDownStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  ...
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid x:Name="DropDownButtonPanel">
          ... 
          <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
            <Button.Template>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="BlackSection"/> 
              ...

          <Button Grid.Column="1" Click="OnButtonClick">
            <Button.Template>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="GreenSection"/> 
              ...

        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" SourceName="DropDownButtonPanel">
            ...
          </Trigger>
        ...
```

How can I access elements from BlackSection and GreenSection in the ControlTemplate.Triggers. Just setter TargetName = "Name" is not useful.

PS. I use two buttons inside one to handle different Click events. Another solution will be a Click event for Grid element, but I also do not know how to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You may be able to alter certain aspects of the child buttons by applying a style.

However, this whole thing seems messy. A "Button" control is just that, something with two states (pressed or unpressed), and an optional command to be invoked when it is pressed. It sounds like you are trying to shoehorn more functionality into it. Can you explain further why you need two buttons on your template?

Comment: Sure. I want to create drop-down button. When you click black section - it works as usual button. When green section - list with other commands are appeared. It's like default action and additional

Comment: That sounds like a UserControl, not a button. A Button has no knowledge of lists of commands. Or you might possibly be able to change the template of a ComboBox.

Comment: Yes - this is user control that has button and popup (with listbox). Functional part is not a problem. I just want to highlight it all without code-behind

Comment: But the template you posted is for a Button, not a UserControl

Comment: Because I need custom appearance only for button. How can it help me if I do global template for the whole control?

Comment: If you need a custom appearance only for one button, then why does your button template have two buttons in it? This was my original question.

Comment: As I noticed in question - to handle two different click events. And I think that this is not necessary to use button as container for two others. It can be any panel.